# why accessing values of a list in different ways gives different classes?

Tags: r, dataframe

Creating a list of dataframes:

`my_dict <- list(df1=read.table("file1", skip=19, sep='\t', header=TRUE), df2=read.table("file2", skip=19, sep='\t', header=TRUE) )`

Why is `class(my_dict["file1"])` a list and `my_dict$file1` a dataframe?
What if I need to access `my_dict$file1` with a variable instead of file1 directly?

example:
`a <- "file1"`

`my_dict$a` gives NULL

Comment: Use `class(my_dict[["file1"]])`